# List multiplication with class constructor

Tags: python, list, operators

Let's say I have a python class (implementation is irrelevant), say it's class "A" as such:

```python-repl
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
```

Then for some reason, I need a list of 3 instance of class "A". I use the following syntax (multiplication operator) to create it:

```python-repl
>>> some_a = [A(),] * 3
>>> len(some_a)
3
```

Great! Looks like we have and array of tree instances of "A". But if we print the `some_a` array, it appears (looking at the object address) that we have 3 reference to the same instance:

```python-repl
>>> repr(some_a)
'[<__main__.A object at 0x7fc6fec7e290>, <__main__.A object at 0x7fc6fec7e290>, <__main__.A object at 0x7fc6fec7e290>]'
```

Why it the behavior as such ? What it the rational behind it ?

I was not able to find the documentation of the multiplication operator effect on lists in the python language reference, can someone point me to it ?

Comment: That's how multiplying lists work. If you want 3 different objects use `[A() for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: @matszwecja Yes, I figured that out. But I want to understand why it is so.

Comment: because that's how the `*` operator is implemented for lists

Comment: Before you can multiply a list, you need to actually *have* a list, so `A()` gets called and "forced" into a single value. Only then you can you can do `list * n`, and by this time list contains only a reference for the already created object.

Comment: Think about a list not as a list containing objects, but of addresses. each list entry points towards an object in memory.  If you copy the phone number of your friend, you wont have a second friend. This pointer logic is more explicit in other languanges like C and C++. Python tries to hide this but in some instances it pops up.